# jQuery .load loading page with unclickable items

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-delegation

I have a couple `.load`'s in my page and originally everything worked fine, and now, after adding some animation in the background, nothing is working. The page loads and looks fine in the window I told it to load in, but nothing is clickable. I have one page with a couple `<a>` links and another with a small form, and they work fine on their own, but when I load it into the main page using:

```
 $("#NewThreadLink").on('click', function () {
    $("#html_NewThread").load("post-thread.php");
  });
```

The page loads fine, but nothing is clickable. I tried turning off all the background animations and images, thinking it might have something to do with it, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Show some HTML & CSS or a demo. It sounds like you have something overlaying the page.

Comment: any js errors in the console?

Comment: probably just need to bind the on to the document and delegate accordingly since the page is loaded dynamically. Try something like $(document).on('click', 'LINK_SELECTOR', function() {//...});

Comment: Could you explain some more, @Huangism. I think it's not recognizing any events attached to the elements in the loaded pages. There are no errors in the console. I'm going to see if I can find a way to write up a demo. If there was a way to make sure events are working for loaded pages, that might fix it.

Comment: @jamil Can you post an example of the click bindings you have set up for the post-thread.php page? Your bindings are not working most likely because you are loading the page dynamically so the new elements are not bind to any events. You can read up on .on http://api.jquery.com/on/ post some code then we can go from there

Comment: @Huangism isherwood had it correct actually. the loaded pages take up a lot more space than the actual content, so I had to shift the z-indices whenever i loaded one.